# Currency symbol oddity in Python. Same code, different system, different outcome why?

Tags: python, currency

The currency symbol is not always a symbol. How to ensure that it is always a symbol and not a 2 char string?

Example:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
conv=locale.localeconv()
print('Currency code:', conv['int_curr_symbol'])
print('Currency symbol:', conv['currency_symbol'])
```

On some systems the result for currency symbol is "€" on others it is "Eu"

I did find a way to, at least so far, get a consistent currency symbol on all systems with the help of "forex_python" package.

Example:

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyCodes
print('Currency symbols')
c = CurrencyCodes()
print('GBP:', c.get_symbol('GBP'))
print('EUR:',c.get_symbol('EUR'))
print('THB:',c.get_symbol('THB'))
print('USD', c.get_symbol('USD'))
```

Comment: It depends on the locale itself, which may differ between systems.

Comment: On ubuntu 19.10 "de_DE" currency was `EUR` but when I switched to `de_DE.UTF-8` I got `€`. I'm hesitant to make this an answer because its a sample size of 1.

Comment: `de_DE.ISO-8859-1` was `EUR`

Comment: Can you specify the encoding as well to be `UTF-8`? Different systems may prefer different encodings for the locale.

Answer (score 3):

**nh-currency** library of Python provides one of the best solutions for processing currency information.

**Here is a working demo printing currency symbols:**

```
# File name:      currency-symbols-demo.py
# Pre-requisite:  pip3 install nh-currency

import currency

print('INR : ' + currency.symbol('INR'))
print('GBP : ' + currency.symbol('GBP'))
print('EUR : ' + currency.symbol('EUR'))
print('USD : ' + currency.symbol('USD'))
```

**Output:**

```
$ python3 currency-symbols-demo.py 

INR : ₹
GBP : £
EUR : €
USD : $
```

**More information:**

https://pypi.org/project/nh-currency/

Comment: Thanks. I found the forex_python library which pretty much does the same 

Answer (score 1):

Since using the locale is only useful related to the local machine an alternative solution is required.

I found the Python library forex_python.
See working code example on repl.it: https://repl.it/join/jitjazjz-dmenis

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyCodes

print('Currency symbols')
c = CurrencyCodes()
print('GBP:', c.get_symbol('GBP'))
print('EUR:',c.get_symbol('EUR'))
print('THB:',c.get_symbol('THB'))
print('USD', c.get_symbol('USD'))
```

So for now I'll go with forex_python but if I need additional functionality for rounding etc then I'll consider py-currency (nh-currency) or perhaps django-money.

Also forex_python seems to be an active project on Github maintained by a Company that specialises in Python developments https://micropyramid.com/